# Linear regression model incorrectly calculated in R

Tags: r, plot, lm, abline

I have 3 different datasets that I have been plotting this way:

[image: Aucune description]

Each dataset was imported from a file to a data frame (respectively called `vues`, `likes` and `commentaires`), and contains the date and the corresponding data (either views, likes or comments) for each date.
Now, I'd like to plot both linear models onto my graph (likes ~ views and comments ~ views).

Starting with the red one, I entered the following code:

```
abline(lm(likes$X2022.12.30 ~ vues$X2022.12.30,data=c(likes,vues)),col="red")
```

And this is what RStudio plots:

[image: Aucune description]

Now I don't understand if the problem comes from the dataset or somewhere else, but if I remove the `data` parameter, or just choose one of the two datasets, it still does the exact same thing, i.e. the following:

```
abline(lm(likes$X2022.12.30 ~ vues$X2022.12.30,data=likes),col="red")
abline(lm(likes$X2022.12.30 ~ vues$X2022.12.30,data=vues),col="red")
abline(lm(likes$X2022.12.30 ~ vues$X2022.12.30),col="red")
```

Here is my data:

```
> vues$X2022.12.30
  [1]   15900    8245    4531  546800    7149   10600    7774   45600  157100
 [10]  348300   15000    7363   24000    6073    6469    5848   13100  185600
 [19]   18700    7622  483800    6373   12000    7839   17100   10800    9846
 [28]    5671   10100    8330    9031  183000   17600    5153  117700   39600
 [37]   10300   27900   11200   29500  387800   15000    8968  465800   72500
 [46]    9501    5816    9761    5814   16200  269700    8905   16300   14700
 [55]  149600    7547  422600   40700   71100   18900  942000   12100   13400
 [64]  551900   16500   12000    8648  131900   10700   18400  183700   13500
 [73]   21500 1203000   14300   14700  108400    5233  388800  368400 1411000
 [82]  286400   17900  261500 1049000   13500   11200   74300 1312000    6044
 [91]   22200    9467    5975  143200    4552  502700    3971    9755   32000
[100]   46800    8844   31600    3671   60700    8249   20100   14500    3475
[109]    5745    2420  193700    2305   13500   90200    5746    5520   29200
[118]    7803    2502    4559    2120    3233  242100    5616    1371    1109
[127]    2123    2097    4019    1444    1515    2350   34600    2642  148000
[136]    2139  541400   13700   52600  421700    9876    3671   33600    6388
[145]   12300    3014   50200    2033   45900    5878    2221    1479
```

```
> likes$X2022.12.30
  [1]   1572    935    229  39000    471    944    472   2149  15400  42000   1346
 [12]    517   1977    488    569    462   1940  17200   2121    588  84800    587
 [23]    987    618   1229    862    947    278   1048    628    795  19200   1529
 [34]    319   9050   3119    868   2840    780   1912  40100   1130    759  47800
 [45]   4197    815    470    786    502   1068  33200    698   1145   1442  11200
 [56]    534  41600   3740   5119   2376  91700    904    983  20800    812    869
 [67]    571   6653    807   1356   7332   1005   1597 104700   1171    982  14300
 [78]    367  14900  29800 103500  11900   1073  22700  67700    872    894   3673
 [89] 116800    251   2229    593    392  20400    267  29200    449    569   1933
[100]   2260   1031   3035    311   6370   1014    812    956    241    641    116
[111]   6543    113    503   5505    450    410   2067    494     76    350    155
[122]    122  11400    350     51     42    109     96    200     62     53     98
[133]   1207    153  15500    101  56900    718   4498  23600    619    248   1803
[144]    437    983    234   4188    147   2623    591    176    138
```

And here is the code I used for plotting the graph if that is relevant:

```
plot.new()
par(mar=c(4,4,4,4))
par(new=TRUE)
par(bg="#FFECDE")
rect(par("usr")[1], par("usr")[3],
     par("usr")[2], par("usr")[4],
     col = c("#E1DEFF"))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(vues$X2022.12.30,likes$X2022.12.30,col="red",axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="",
     main="Nombre de j'aime et de commentaires en fonction du nombre de vues",
     pch=-0x2022,bg="red")
axis(2,ylim=c(0,120000),col="red", col.axis="red",at=seq(0, 120000, by=20000)) 
mtext("Nombre de j'aime",side=2,line=2.5,col="red")
box()
par(new=TRUE)
plot(vues$X2022.12.30,commentaires$X2022.12.30,col="blue",axes=FALSE,xlab="",
     ylab="",ylim=c(0,1500),pch=-0x2022,bg="blue")
axis(4,col="blue",col.axis="blue",at=seq(0, 1500, by=250)) 
mtext("Nombre de commentaires",side=4,line=2.5,col="blue")
axis(1,xlim=c(0,1500000),ylim=c(0,145000),col="black",col.axis="black",
     at=seq(0, 1400000, by=100000)) 
mtext("Nombre de vues",side=1,line=2.5,col="black")
legend(x="topleft",legend=c("J'aime","Commentaires"),
       text.col=c("black","black"),pch=c(-0x2022,-0x2022),col=c("red","blue"),
       bg=c("#C9FFF1"),inset=0.02)
```

Comment: If you made the points first (i.e., did all of the code at the bottom of your post first), then the problem comes is that R sees Comments as the y-axis and you're plotting a line that uses Likes (rather than comments) as the y-variable.  If you did the `abline()` function before `par(new=TRUE)`, my guess is that it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `par(new=TRUE)` and overplotting the commentaries data changes the y-axis scale; `abline()` is still assuming the old scale is in effect.

The simple solution would be to use `abline()` to add the regression line *before* you add the commentaries data.

Example:

```r
dd <- data.frame(vues=
c(15900,8245,4531,546800,7149,10600,7774,45600,157100,
348300,15000,7363,24000,6073,6469,5848,13100,185600,
18700,7622,483800,6373,12000,7839,17100,10800,9846,
5671,10100,8330,9031,183000,17600,5153,117700,39600,
10300,27900,11200,29500,387800,15000,8968,465800,72500,
9501,5816,9761,5814,16200,269700,8905,16300,14700,
149600,7547,422600,40700,71100,18900,942000,12100,13400,
551900,16500,12000,8648,131900,10700,18400,183700,13500,
21500,1203000,14300,14700,108400,5233,388800,368400,1411000,
286400,17900,261500,1049000,13500,11200,74300,1312000,6044,
22200,9467,5975,143200,4552,502700,3971,9755,32000,
46800,8844,31600,3671,60700,8249,20100,14500,3475,
5745,2420,193700,2305,13500,90200,5746,5520,29200,
7803,2502,4559,2120,3233,242100,5616,1371,1109,
2123,2097,4019,1444,1515,2350,34600,2642,148000,
2139,541400,13700,52600,421700,9876,3671,33600,6388,
12300,3014,50200,2033,45900,5878,2221,1479),
likes = c(1572,935,229,39000,471,944,472,2149,15400,42000,1346,
517,1977,488,569,462,1940,17200,2121,588,84800,587,
987,618,1229,862,947,278,1048,628,795,19200,1529,
319,9050,3119,868,2840,780,1912,40100,1130,759,47800,
4197,815,470,786,502,1068,33200,698,1145,1442,11200,
534,41600,3740,5119,2376,91700,904,983,20800,812,869,
571,6653,807,1356,7332,1005,1597,104700,1171,982,14300,
367,14900,29800,103500,11900,1073,22700,67700,872,894,3673,
116800,251,2229,593,392,20400,267,29200,449,569,1933,
2260,1031,3035,311,6370,1014,812,956,241,641,116,
6543,113,503,5505,450,410,2067,494,76,350,155,
122,11400,350,51,42,109,96,200,62,53,98,
1207,153,15500,101,56900,718,4498,23600,619,248,1803,
437,983,234,4188,147,2623,591,176,138))
set.seed(101)
dd$other <- runif(nrow(dd), min=0, max = 1500)

plot(likes~vues, data =dd)
abline(lm(likes~vues, data =dd))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(other~vues, data = dd, axes=FALSE, col = 2)
abline(lm(likes~vues, data =dd), col =4, lwd =2)
```